# Not initializing state from props

Tags: reactjs

i am using React version " 17.0.1" and when i try to initialize component state from props so it's not working it just initialize state with undefined. Following example will illustrate my problem..
component `Two`

```
    class Two extends React.Component {
     state = {
       name: this.props.option.name
      }
     render(){
       console.log(this.state.name)

     return (
       <div>
          {this.state.name}
       </div>
      )
    }
}
```

and component `One` is:

```
    class One extends React.Component {
     render(){
        return  <Two option={name='riaz'} />
       }
     }
```

in component `Two` i am trying to initialize state from props but it just initialize it with undefined

```
ReactDOM.render(<One />,document.getElementById('app'))
```

And i have installed and configured the `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class One extends React.Component {
     render(){
        return  <Two option={name='riaz'} />
       }
     }
```

should be

```
class One extends React.Component {
     render(){
        return  <Two option={{name:'riaz'}} />
       }
     }
```

They way you're accessing it tells me that your `option` is an object which has a property `name`. So you need to also pass it as such.

Also I think @Konstantin Samarin is right in saying to have a proper constructor when dealing with props in class component.

So your constructor will be :-

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
       name: this.props.option.name
  }
}
```

But this isn't advised by React. You can see the same in the link for docs shared by him.

Comment: thank you so much. you are absolutely right. the problem was in the < Two option={name='riaz'} /> it should have be < Two option={{ name: 'riaz' }} />

Answer (score 1):

You should also call constructor method and initialize props like so:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
       name: this.props.option.name
  }
}
```

Otherwise props are undefined, check official documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor. Still it is not a best practice to copy props into state.

Comment: i have tried that too, but not working that too

Comment: Thank you for your answer but what is the best way to initialize state from props???

Comment: You should only do this if it is really needed. For example, depending on user actions state will change: order, what is shown, moved etc. If it is static rendering you do not need this at all, simply use props.

Comment: yeah i know but when we need to initialize the state from props then what is the recommended way to do that ????

Comment: Anyway the problem is solved. I had just passed props with incorrect object as mentioned by @Lakshya Thakur,  but now it's working fine